# In a Dictionary, How to convert a string into a list?

Tags: python, dictionary

In a Dictionary, How to convert a string into a list?
Let

```
x = ['P: 7678643 F: 123456 E: ttt@jhj.in']
```

Need to convert to:

```
y = ['P: 7678643', 'F: 123456', 'E: ttt@jhj.in']
```

Comment: There's no dictionary in sight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite that the question is all wrong, here's a some solution:

```
import re
x = ['P: 7678643 F: 123456 E: ttt@jhj.in']
Split = re.split(' ', x[0])
y = []
for i in range(0, len(Split), 2):
    y.append(Split[i] + Split[i+1])
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no dictionary in your code example. According to your code I would use a regular expression with a negative lookbehind.

```
x = ['P: 7678643 F: 123456 E: ttt@jhj.in']
y = re.split('(?<!:)\s', x[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
x = ['P: 7678643 F: 123456 E: ttt@jhj.in']
result = re.findall(r'\w+:\s\w+',x[0])
```